# Footer with copyright and social media icons won't center vertically

Tags: html, css, alignment, footer

Working on making my website. I'm sure this is an easy fix but I'm so stuck!

I am trying to vertically center the copyright info on the right, then the social icons on the left. But they appear to be stacked then aligned left and right.

[Here's what that looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjgo4.png)

Please forgive the dumb question. Very new to all this, and I've done as much troubleshooting as I can. I'm hoping is a "duh" answer!

I have a footer in my index which reads like this:

```css
 #main-footer {
  padding: center;
  background: darken($primary-color, 10);
  color: set-text-colour($primary-color);
  height: 60px;

  .footer_text {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  .footer_icons {
    margin-left: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px;
    a {
      align: left;

      &:hover {
        color: $secondary-color;
        @include easeOut;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<footer id="main-footer">

  <div class="footer_text">Copyright &copy; 2018</div>

  <div class="footer_icons">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/beellllaa/">
      <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/beellllaa/">
      <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.vimeo.com/beellllaa/">
      <i class="fab fa-vimeo fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

- Readjust your HTML so that your .footer_text div comes after the .footer_icons div.
- Add the following lines of CSS to your #main_footer div.

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

See the code snippet below or [this codepen](https://codepen.io/t1mwillis/pen/rZopZd):

```css
#main-footer {
  padding: center;
  background: darken($primary-color, 10);
  color: set-text-colour($primary-color);
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .footer_text {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  .footer_icons {
    margin-left: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px;
    a {
      align: left;

      &:hover {
        color: $secondary-color;
        @include easeOut;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
 <footer id="main-footer">



  <div class="footer_icons">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/beellllaa/">
      <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x">IG</i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/beellllaa/">
      <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x">LI</i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.vimeo.com/beellllaa/">
      <i class="fab fa-vimeo fa-2x">VI</i>
    </a>
  </div>
   
   <div class="footer_text">Copyright &copy; 2018</div>

</footer>
```

Comment: Tim Willis you genius ! Thank you :')

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to directly use your code via codepen, so I mocked up something quick. You could quickly center vertically by using flexbox. This might require though that you use some prefixes as well. Can check it out here:

https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1100

```css
#main-footer {
  background-color: teal;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.social {
  display: flex;
}

.footer-icons {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<footer id="main-footer">
  <div>Copyright &copy; 2018</div>
  
  <div class="social">
    <div class="footer-icons"></div>
    <div class="footer-icons"></div>
    <div class="footer-icons"></div>
  </div>
  
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
$primary-color:white;
$secondary-color:white;
#main-footer {
  padding: center;
  background: darken($primary-color, 10);
  color: set-text-colour($primary-color);
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;

  .footer_text {
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height:60px;
    float: right;
  }

  .footer_icons {
    margin-left: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 4px;
    a {
      align: left;
      padding-right:10px;

      &:hover {
        color: $secondary-color;
      }
    }
  }
}

i{
  font-family:'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
 <footer id="main-footer">

  <div class="footer_icons">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/beellllaa/">
      <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/beellllaa/">
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.vimeo.com/beellllaa/">
      <i class="fa fa-vimeo fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
   <div class="footer_text">Copyright &copy; 2018</div>

</footer>
```

This should work. `.footer_text{float:right;line-height:60px;}` `.footer_icons{display:inline-block;}`

Codepen Link : https://codepen.io/mk_dev/pen/KxbyJp